# Force a re-render (update the state and update the DOM) immediately with react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I realize that calling `setState` does not update `this.state` immediately, nor does it immediately call `render` and refresh the DOM. The docs say

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

I would like to be able to force a "state transition" like this at any point. This seems like it ought to be a fairly natural operation, but I can't find any mention of it in the docs. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What's your use case? You might be more interested in atomic [`setState`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate).

Comment: What are you trying to do that has this requirement?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `forceUpdate` for this:

> If your render() method reads from something other than this.props or
>   this.state, you'll need to tell React when it needs to re-run render()
>   by calling forceUpdate(). You'll also need to call forceUpdate() if
>   you mutate this.state directly.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate

Comment: I'm not sure if `forceUpdate` does what I want (maybe it does, but either way, it isn't clear.) I thought the point of `forceUpdate` was to make the element re-render even without setting state, but that this render could still get queued like any render. Is that correct or wrong?

Comment: That's correct. `forceUpdate` causes the component to render into vDOM _elements_, but it does not force a flush of the vDOM to the actual DOM (not sure how to achieve what you want)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `forceUpdate` in conjunction with having a key on the top level component as so..

```
let key= 0;

var Hello = React.createClass({

  sudoForceUpdate(){
    key++;
    this.forceUpdate();   
  },
  render: function(){
    return <div key={key}>Example</div>;
  }
});
```

By editing the key and forcing an update, the dom will always rerender.

Here is an example that highlights the difference between just a force edit, and one with a key change*.

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/82763/

*note that this is likely pretty bad practice.

*Thanks to Ben Alpert:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/8JgClU9jol0*